# How to use IHttpCookieContainerManager in WCF 4.5

Tags: wcf

Just wanted to know how can we use IHttpCookieContainerManager in WCF 4.5. Suggest any sample code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 4.5 you can access the cookie container by using the .GetProperty().CookieContainer method like below if AllowCoookies = true.

```
        Uri serverUri = new Uri("http://localhost/WcfService/Service1.svc");
        CookieContainer myCookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        myCookieContainer.Add(serverUri, new Cookie("cookie1", "cookie1Value"));

        ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(new BasicHttpBinding() { AllowCookies = true }, new EndpointAddress(serverUri));
        IService1 client = factory.CreateChannel();
        factory.GetProperty<IHttpCookieContainerManager>().CookieContainer = myCookieContainer;


        Console.WriteLine(client.GetData(123));

        myCookieContainer = factory.GetProperty<IHttpCookieContainerManager>().CookieContainer;
        foreach (Cookie receivedCookie in myCookieContainer.GetCookies(serverUri))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cookie name : " + receivedCookie.Name + " Cookie value : " + receivedCookie.Value);
        }

        ((IChannel)client).Close();
        factory.Close();
```

//Server side

```
public class Service1 : IService1
   {
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        //Read the cookies
        HttpRequestMessageProperty reqProperty = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
        string cookies = reqProperty.Headers["Cookie"];

        //Write a cookie
        HttpResponseMessageProperty resProperty = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
        resProperty.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", string.Format("Number={0}", value.ToString()));
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, resProperty);
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: To note the old style of cookie management by setting in the OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties will continue to work like before.